# How could i start two new window with two thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'd like to open a window in a thread. I'd like to use the Thread class as you can see in my code:

```
namespace WFPThreadin {

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static Window1 win1;
    private static Window2 win2;
    Thread tid1, tid2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void gomb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Button)sender).Name == "button1")
        {
            tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainWindow.winshow1));
            tid1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            tid1.Start();
        }

        if (((Button)sender).Name == "button2")
        {
            tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainWindow.winshow2));
            tid2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            tid2.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void winshow1()
    {
        win1 = new Window1();
        win1.Show();
    }

    public static void winshow2()
    {
        win2 = new Window2();
        win2.Show();
    }

}}
```

It doesn't works well, because when i clicking the button1 (or button2) the window1 (or window2) showed for a moment...
If you have any suggestion for solve my problem i could appreciate that!

Comment: You are creating a window in a thread.When the thread ends the window(resource allocated by the thread) exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Running on the Same UI Thread:**

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
             new Thread(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        Window2 w2 = new Window2();
                        w2.Show();
                    }));
            }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                Window3 w3 = new Window3();
                w3.Show();
            }));
        }).Start();

 }
```

**Running on Two Different Threads:**

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

Thread   _firstWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CallWindow1));
        _firstWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _firstWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        _firstWindowThread.Start();


Thread  _secondWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CallWindow2));
        _secondWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _secondWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        _secondWindowThread.Start();


  } 


  private void CallWindow1()
    {
        Window2 w2 = new Window2();
        w2.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }

    private void CallWindow2()
    {
        Window3 w3 = new Window3();
        w3.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

For more details take a look at [WPF Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)

Comment: What is the difference between calling the function directly and this code?Anyway it's going to run in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, as soon as i can i'll react about your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with Task instead of using Thread

```
 if (((Button)sender).Name == "button1")
    {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>winshow1());
    }

    if (((Button)sender).Name == "button2")
    {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>winshow2());
    }
```